# secret message python-encoding logic

Tags: python, python-3.x

## encoding logic

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
newMessage = ''
  
message = input('Please enter a message: ')

key = input('Enter a key (1-26): ')
key = int(key)

for character in message:
  if character in alphabet:
    position = alphabet.find(character)
    newPosition = (position - key) % 26
    newCharacter = alphabet[newPosition]
    newMessage += newCharacter
```

What is the use of "% 26".I know that by using this the index stays in limits of 0-26 , but wanted to know if this is specific to python and if it is a math logic or some python notation

Answer (score 0):

The `% 26` is referred to in programming languages *and* math as **the modulus operator**. Essentially, it's the remainder of division.

For example `2 % 4 = 0` (read as "two MOD four"). 2 goes into 4 twice with 0 left over.

`2 % 5 = 1` because 2 goes into 5 twice with 1 left over `(5 - (2 * 2))`.

The modulus operator is especially useful when determining the parity of a number. If any number `N % 2 = 0`, the parity **has to be even**. Otherwise, it's odd.

In this scenario, the `% 26` enforces the algorithm to stay within the bounds of the alphabet. Otherwise, you'd be getting an `IndexError` exception.

Hope that helps!